# Como utilizar a API NFePHP sem que haja a necessidade do server suportar cURL 7.22.2

Tags: php, libcurl, nfe

Existe alguma possibilidade de utilizar a API NFePHP sem que haja a necessidade do *server* suportar `cURL 7.22.2`? Alguma configuração que eu possa realizar, uma lib alternativa, etc?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Trabalhei com essa API em 2015, e até tenho um emissor de nota fiscal desenvolvido.
A informação da época era que não era possível trabalhar sem o cURL. De qualquer forma, me fala sobre o servidor que está usando para ver se eu posso ajudar a habilitar o cURL.

Comment: http://bwdagenciadigital.com/info.php @PauloSérgioDuff

Comment: CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 kvm | 16 núcleos | AMD Opteron | Plano Revenda 1 da HostGator

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, ao que tudo indica a resposta é não, não existe.

A extensão cURL do PHP é utilizada diretamente no acesso aos webservices.

No PHP versão 5.3.x o cURL já tem a versão mínima, então acredito que esta sua versão 7.19.7 seja do PHP 5.2 ou anterior.

Recomendo você tentar outro caminho atualizando o SO ou migrando para um SO que tenha este pré-requisito.

Sobre o PHP, de preferência utilize a versão 5.6 prá cima.

Abraços.

Comment: Olá @FernandoMertins, a versão do PHP já foi atualizada para a versão 7.0.14 e utilizo um plano de revenda da HostGator.